# How should I use onPress when mapping an array to a button element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, function, mapping

If I'm mapping an array and each should be a button, how would I design the onPress function, since the amount of buttons will vary depending on the user?

I currently have 3 buttons using react native elements where each has a regular style, a disabled style and the disabled prop (true or false). I have 3 states (false as inital state) one for each button. Each button has an onPress, which sets each state. True for the one I pressed, false for the rest. How can I apply this to a unknown number of buttons?

Current code:

```
//fetched data:
const names : [{name: Bob, age: 20},{name: Lisa, age: 26}, {name: Tom, age: 24}, ...];

const [button1, setButton1] = useState(false);
const [button2, setButton2] = useState(false);
const [button3, setButton3] = useState(false);
const [clickedName, setClickedName] = useState("");

const btn1sel = () => {
   setButton1(true);
   setButton2(false);
   setButton3(false);
   setClickedName("Bob");
};

const btn2sel = () => {
   setButton1(false);
   setButton2(true);
   setButton3(false);
   setClickedName("Lisa");
};

const btn3sel = () => {
   setButton1(false);
   setButton2(false);
   setButton3(true);
   setClickedName("Tom");
};

const App = () => {
   return(
      <View>
         <Button style={styles.btn} disabledStyle={styles.btnD} disabled={button1} onPress={btn1sel1} />
         <Button style={styles.btn} disabledStyle={styles.btnD} disabled={button2} onPress={btn1sel2} />
         <Button style={styles.btn} disabledStyle={styles.btnD} disabled={button3} onPress={btn1sel3} />
         <Text>{clickedName}</Text>
      </View>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a useState hook to store your array and update it like this:

```
const [names, setNames] = React.useState([{ name: 'Bob', age: 20, disabled: false }, { name: 'Lisa', age: 26, disabled: false }, { name: 'Tom', age: 24, disabled: false }])

const btn = (item, index) => {
    const arr = [...names]
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
        arr[i].disabled = false
    }
    arr[index].disabled = true
    setClickedName(item.name)
    setNames(arr)
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            {names.map((item, index) => {
                <Button style={styles.btn} disabledStyle={styles.btnD} disabled={item.disabled} onPress={() => btn(item, index)} />
            })}
            <Text>{clickedName}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I just got the chance to finally test this, and this was the solution! It works perfectly. Thank you for your help!